# Swift/Parse - Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type '(PFUser?, (PFObject?, NSError?) -> Void)'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I got this error message when trying to search object UserDetail.

Error message

```
/Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/ViewController.swift:125:15: Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type '(PFUser?, (PFObject?, NSError?) -> Void)'
```

My code

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        var query = PFQuery(className:"UserDetail")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user) { //error message here
            (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
                gameScore["cheatMode"] = true
                gameScore["score"] = 1338
                gameScore.saveInBackground()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong parameter types in the block passed to `PFQuery`'s `getObjectInBackground(_:block:)` method. According to [the docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:), the `block` argument takes an `NSArray` (this can be bridged to a Swift array of `AnyObject`), and an error:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user?.objectId) { (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

In addition, the `objectId` parameter should be a string, but you appear to be passing in a `PFUser` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert, but looking at documentation I see it accepts String as parameter instead of object.

Try using:

`query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user?.objectId)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` this way:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("yourUser", block: {
        (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        //your code

    })
```

As you can see syntax for `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` is:

[image]